# hibernate annotations: map a list that keeps order

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I want to do a one to many mapping that keeps order. The order itself is complex and related to business logic and does not have a single field or simple logic that can represent it.

What I want is to load an object, swap two elements (or more) in the list and save and do `session.update(object)`. I expect next time the element is loaded to keep the right order however it does not.

What I am doing:

```
@Entity
 public class Product {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

  blah blah blah

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@OrderColumn`did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

With `javax.persistence.OrderBy` you can sort on several columns, which usually works in most cases.

If the order is more complex I would suggest to add a separate method that performs the sorting in memory and returns the sorted list (as unmodifiable).

In all cases, I don't think there exists a solution that would allow to swap elements in the list such that Hibernate would understand how to update the swapped entities (even with only the order on 1 field): you have to update the child entities by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the purpose of the LIST mapping in Hibernate :

```
   <list name="friends">
      <key column="M_ID" not-null="true"/>
      <list-index column="M_INDEX"/>
      <one-to-many class="Person"/>
   </list>
```

For annotations you need to use @OrderBy, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexed

Comment: thank you. please refer to hibernate annotations. (I have clarified my question)